# Lower case the letter after punctuation using regex python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am writing a regex equation to change uppercase letter to lowercase that follows the punctuation semicolon (:).

```
str = "hello: You"
re.sub("(.*):(\s.*?)([A-Za-z]+)",lambda p: p.group(3).lower(),str)
```

> you

when the word is alphanumeric it should not do anything. that's y group(3) in regex includes not alphabets.

```
str = "hello: 12AE12"
re.sub("(.*):(\s.*?)([A-Za-z]+)",lambda p: p.group(3).lower(),str)
```

it returns

> ae12

What am i doing wrong in my regex equation.

Comment: I can't reproduce your second test case.  I get nothing returned from `re.sub`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen His code works for me: https://repl.it/repls/MotionlessDiligentObjectmodel

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you ended up using your current pattern, but I would suggest using this one:

```
.*:\s+([A-Za-z]+)\b
```

You only need to really have one capture group here.  Also, to simplify things, I just consume and ignore a colon, followed by some whitespace, then followed by the capture group.

```
str = "hello: You"
print(re.sub(".*:\s+([A-Za-z]+)\b", lambda p: p.group(1).lower(),str))

you

str = "hello: 12AE12"
print(re.sub(".*:\s+([A-Za-z]+)\b", lambda p: p.group(1).lower(),str))

12AE12
```

Answer (score 0):

Your final group's character set

```
([A-Za-z]+)
```

has no guarantee that it ends at the end of a word. So, if *at least one alphabetical* character can be matched in that group, at the beginning of the word following the `:`, the regex will succeed, even if the word there is actually alphanumeric. Put a word boundary at the end instead, to guarantee that the character set terminates at the end of a word, or that the match will fail entirely:

```
re.sub("(.*):(\s.*?)([A-Za-z]+)\b",lambda p: p.group(3).lower(),str)
#                              ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using or (`|`) statement. If the match is alphanumeric, the word will be matched by the forth group.

```
import re

strs = ["hello: You", "hello: 12AE12"]

p = re.compile(r"(.*):(\s*)(?:([A-Za-z]*)|([A-Za-z0-9]*))$")

for s in strs:
    m = p.search(s)
    if m.group(3):
        print(m.group(3).lower())
    elif m.group(4):
        print(m.group(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
str1 = "hello: You"
str2 = "hello: 12AE12"

def caps_to_lower(obj):
    m = re.search('.*:\s+([a-zA-Z]+)', obj)
    if m:
        return m.group(1).lower()

>>> caps_to_lower(str1)
'you'
>>> caps_to_lower(str2)
>>>
```